# Conditionally add another column in query base on other query result

Tags: mysql

I found the solution for add query column by **case** **when** **then** from same table depending on column value but It can't solve my problem.

I have two tables.
Table: **pools**

```
    id  date        title           description          
------  ----------  --------------  ---------------------
     1  2016-11-10  This is pool 1  this is description
```

Table: **votes**

```
    id  date        time      pool_id  option_id  uid                           
------  ----------  --------  -------  ---------  ------------------------------
     1  2016-11-10  21:22:23        1          1  XodxfBfeRdZsOFRNbJ0AecMgpyo2  
     2  2016-11-10  21:22:23        1          2  PhbZ675XdZeL59QFKLQq8u1uQyg2
```

I want to query output by passing **uid** in query.

```
    id  date        title           voted          
------  ----------  --------------  ---------------------
     1  2016-11-10  This is pool 1  YES
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `LEFT JOIN` 2 tables `pools` and `votes`. Then check if corresponding entry exists in votes, show YES else NO.

For better explanation, I created 1 more entry in pool table.

```
INSERT INTO pools VALUES (2, '2016-11-11', 'This is pool 2', 'this is description');
```

Below Query will give you desired output:

```
SELECT p.id, p.date, p.title, IF(v.id IS NOT NULL, 'YES', 'NO') AS voted
FROM pools p LEFT JOIN votes v
ON p.id = v.pool_id
AND v.uid = 'XodxfBfeRdZsOFRNbJ0AecMgpyo2';
```

> Query Explanation

`LEFT JOIN` will return row from LHS table and NULL from RHS table if corresponding value is not present.

We can then add a check in `SELECT` statement to create custom column `voted`.

> OUTPUT

```
id  date        title          voted
-------------------------------------
1  2016-11-10  This is pool 1  YES   
2  2016-11-11  This is pool 2  NO
```